# Error Validar Login PHP, error en password_verify

Tags: php, mysql, login

Siguiendo este video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWlRLTylSJM&list=PLN9W6BC54TJI6mlpAT-b7nDkpHbZp73i4&index=29) y con un arreglo que hice desde otra consulta he llegado a esta situación:

El registro me funciona, y cuando voy a logearme no funciona, tengo la contraseña incorrecta se indica en ValidadorLogin, estoy investigando como arreglar este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ValidadorLogin (*Aqui es dondese detecta el error indicado en un comentario*):

```
public function __construct($email, $clave, $conexion)
{
    $this -> error = "";
    if (!$this -> variable_iniciada($email) || !$this -> variable_iniciada($clave)){
        $this -> usuario = null;
        $this -> error = "Debes introducir tu email y tu contraseña";
    } else {
        $this -> usuario = RepositorioUsuario::obtener_usuario_por_email($conexion, $email);
        
        //comprobamos si la contaseña no es correcta(descifrandola) 
        //la contraseña es lo que me da fallo(password_verify)
            if(is_null($this -> usuario) || !password_verify($clave, $this -> usuario -> obtener_password())){
           
            $this -> error = "Datos incorrectos";
        }
    }
}
```

RepositorioUsuario:

```
public static function obtener_usuario_por_email($conexion, $email){
        $usuario = null;

        if(isset($conexion)/*Conexion existe*/){
            try{
                include_once "Usuario.inc.php";
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email";
                $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
                $sentencia -> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sentencia -> execute();
                $sentencia->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Usuario');
                $usuario=array();

                while ($row = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $usuario[]=$row;
                }
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                print 'ERROR'.$ex -> getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $usuario;
    }
```

Archivo usuario.inc(Aqui tengo la clase de obtener_password):

```
public function obtener_password(){
            return $this -> password;
        }
```

Adjunto el error, la linea 23 es la imagen superior.:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function obtener_password() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\app\ValidadorLogin.inc.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\clientes\login_c.php(8): ValidadorLogin->__construct('ismaelmontoyaco...', '1234', Object(PDO)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\app\ValidadorLogin.inc.php on line 23

Comment: Hay errores en el log?

Comment: He conseguido captar algunos errores pero no encuentro el de la contraseña